# Multiple combination search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for multiple field  combination by multiple queries. 
Must with be combination plus  multiple release and release_type queries required.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "fpc_type":  "AZCE 4D 24X+7LGE" }}, 
        { "match": { "re_type": "S-300x4" }}, 
        { "match": { "platform": "PX480" }}, 
        { "match": { "rpd_bit": "64" }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "term": [
     {
        "release_name": "16",
        "release_type": "test_type2"
     },
     {
        "release_name": "15.1",
        "release_type": "test_type1"
     }
   ]
}
```

Not sure I am in right path. 
Main Comnination

```
{ "match": { "fpc_type":  "AZCE 4D 24X+7LGE" }}, 
        { "match": { "re_type": "S-300x4" }}, 
        { "match": { "platform": "PX480" }}, 
        { "match": { "rpd_bit": "64" }}
```

Need query like

```
Main combination +  {
        "release_name": "15.1",
        "release_type": "test_type1"
     }
Main combination + {
        "release_name": "16",
        "release_type": "test_type2"
     }
```

Not getting how to build query.

Comment: combine `should` with `must` may work. request `_explain` to know how the _score calculates.

Comment: placing should with must is not working. First of all I am not sure whether I should use term or not there